# Dictionary item won't display from Python to Jinja2

Tags: python, html, jinja2

This code was working for a bit then suddenly stopped and I can't figure out what happened.

No matter what I get a web page with everything but the hyperlink displayed. There are 4 dots that show up, along with the `h1` and the proper title,

I assume because there are supposed to be four links. But the words/links meant to be there don't show.

The Python code:

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
import glob
import yaml

app = Flask(__name__)

plays = {}

###load data from fn file
for fn in glob.glob('data/*.yaml'):
    with open(fn, 'r') as yf:
        play = yaml.load(yf)
        plays[play['id']] = play

for id, info in plays.items():
    print('The info for {} is {}.'.format(id, info))

@app.route('/')
def showPlayList():
    return flask.render_template('shake_plays.html',         plays=plays.values())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Jinja/html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Plays of Shakespeare</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Plays of Shakespeare</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for id, play in plays.items() %}
            <li><a href="{{ id }}"> {{ play.title }} </a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `plays` dict to template

```
@app.route('/')
def showPlayList():
    return flask.render_template('shake_plays.html', plays=plays)
```

Comment: It does do that, for some reason there is a random space in that part of the code. an upload error on my part I assume.

Comment: You passed list of values (`plays=plays.values()`), not dict

Comment: Forgot I altered that. Sorry. That was added so that i could sort them easier in Jinja. Even when I take it out the same problem persists.